# How can quasi-linear PDE with initial condition and boundary condition using method of characteristics?

Tags: boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems, linear-pde

I’m tackling to solve a 1st order quasi PDE as below 
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\sqrt {u}}{x} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$$

Here, the I.C & B.C are 
$$u(0,x)=u_0 $$ and
$$u(0<t<t_0 ,x_0 ) = u_0 (1-t/t_0 )^2 $$
$$u(t > t_0 ,x_0 )=0 $$

I think I could get the general solution using method of characteristics but I have no idea how to get unique solution from the I.C & B.Cs.

Here is my trials..

The characteristics can be written,

$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{xdx}{\sqrt{u}}=\frac{du}{0}$$

So, from the last term I can get
$${du} = {0} \rightarrow u=k_1$$

And with other relation,

$$k_2 = x^2 - 2t \sqrt{u}$$

The general solution would be $$u(t,x)=f\left( x^2 - 2t \sqrt{u} \right)$$

Applying I.C & B.C I got

$$u(0, x) = u_0 = f(x^2)$$
$$u(t,x_0)|_{0<t<t_0}= u_0\left(1-t/t_0 \right)^2 = f\left({x_0}^2-2t(1-t/t_0)\sqrt{u_0}\right)$$
$$u(t, x_0)|_{t>t_0} = 0 = f\left({x_0}^2 - 2t\sqrt{u} \right)=f\left({x_0}^2 \right)$$

How can I find the unique solution from these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$u(t,x)=f\left( x^2 - 2t \sqrt{u} \right) \qquad\text{OK.}$$
If $u(0,x)=u_0(x)$ is a given function 
$$u(0, x) = u_0(x) = f(x^2)\quad\implies\quad f(X)=u_0(\sqrt{X})$$
The solution on implicit form is :
$$u(t,x)=u_0\left( \sqrt{x^2 - 2t \sqrt{u}} \right)$$
In case of $u_0(x)=$constant, the solution is $\quad u(t,x)=u_0\quad$ which obviously satisfies the PDE.